# What is the exact time span mentioned in this verse of inactivity?

Tags: time, surya, ayurveda

Consider the following sub-verse regarding a time intended for inactivity

> avoid taking foods, sex, sleeping, study and recapitulation at the
> time of **meeting of the night and sunrise**
>
> [p:23, Chapter 2: Dinacharya, Astanga Hridaya Sutrasthan](https://www.planetayurveda.com/ayurveda-ebooks/astanga-hridaya-sutrasthan-handbook.pdf#page=23)

I want to know the exact time or calculation that has been mentioned here. Suppose sunrise is at a particular time, say 6:45 am. Then what is the time span mentioned in the quoted?

Comment: time is a continuum.

Comment: basically aruna and anusha i.e. dawn/dusk. you can see light around half hour before sunrise, and after sunset. 1 muhurtha = 48 minutes. so 2 muhurthas around time of sunrise/sunset. i.e. 48 minutes before and 48 minutes after. can be reduced to half muhurtha (24 minutes) either side when traveling or emergencies.